# How do I center column labels in a pgfplot bar chart?

Tags: pgfplots, bar-chart, nodes-near-coords

I'm drawing a bar chart with `pgfplots`. I need to have the value of each column above the column itself, like this:

**Figure 1**

[image: center aligned bar chart labels]

but LaTeX centers it above the left side:

**Figure 2**

[image: left aligned bar chart labels]

I tried using `nodes near coords align={vertical}` and `nodes near coords align={horizontal}` as `axis` environment's options but the first doesn't do anything and the second makes it worse:

**Figure 3**

[image]

How can I put the labels where I want them without overlapping each other nor the near columns (see value `4000` in the `90` column in figure 2)? I would also like to hide the label for the "hidden" `100` column (visible in figures 2 and 3).

---

Here's a simplified version of the source (possibly overindented, but I find it clearer):

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[xtick=data,
                 xtick pos=left,
                 xticklabel interval boundaries,
                 ybar,
                 ymin=0,
                 scaled y ticks=false,
                 nodes near coords,
                 symbolic x coords={$0$,$10$,$20$,$30$,$40$,$50$,$60$,$70$,$80$,$90$,$100$}]
        \addplot [ybar interval,fill=lightgray]
                 coordinates {($0$, 5)     ($10$, 0)    ($20$, 15)
                              ($30$, 75)   ($40$, 250)  ($50$, 1000)
                              ($60$, 3000) ($70$, 7000) ($80$, 11000)
                              ($90$, 4000) ($100$, 0)};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

N.B.: the class option `twocolumn` seems to be relevant for the label alignment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    width=\linewidth,
    xtick=data,
    xticklabel interval boundaries,
    ybar,
    %bar width=9mm,
    ymin=0,
    scaled y ticks=false,
    nodes near coords,
    nodes near coords style = {font=\footnotesize, anchor=south west, 
                               text width=8mm, inner xsep=0pt, align=center},
    symbolic x coords={$0$,$10$,$20$,$30$,$40$,$50$,$60$,$70$,$80$,$90$,$100$}
            ]
\addplot [ybar interval,fill=lightgray]
         coordinates {($0$, 5)     ($10$, 0)    ($20$, 15)
                      ($30$, 75)   ($40$, 250)  ($50$, 1000)
                      ($60$, 3000) ($70$, 7000) ($80$, 11000)
                      ($90$, 4000) ($100$, 0)};
\end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Addendum:**

According to your comment, that width of the diagram is equal to `columnwidth` and that bars' labels can be rotated:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[11]
\begin{figure}[ht]
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    width=\linewidth,
    ybar,
    xtick=data,
    xticklabel interval boundaries,
    ytick distance=2000,
    xticklabel style= {font=\footnotesize},
    xmax=110, ymin = 0, % had to be smaller than y coordinate
                        % of dummy data y coordinate
    enlarge x limits=0.05,
    enlarge y limits={value=.3,upper},
    scaled y ticks=false,
    nodes near coords,
    nodes near coords style = {font=\small, 
                               xshift=0.75*\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/bar width},
                               rotate=90, anchor=west},
    symbolic x coords={0,10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100,110}
            ]
\addplot [ybar interval,fill=lightgray]
     coordinates {(0,     5) (10,   0) (20,  15) (30,  75)   
                  (40,  250) (50,1000) (60,3000) (70,7000) 
                  (80,11000) (90,4000) (100,  0) (100, 0)
                  (110,-100) % dummy coordinate,
                 };          % option clip=false is prohibited
\end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Diagram}
\label{fig:diagram}
    \end{figure}

See diagram on figure {fig:diagram}
\lipsum[1-4]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I don't know much pgfplots nor tikz, but I think I understand how it should work. However, it doesn't for me: it aligns too much to the right, the most digits, the worst. What I get is [this](https://imgur.com/a/lzywKoy).

Comment: @Ntakwetet, not with my MWE. You change something in it.

Comment: Ouch! Sorry, you're reason - it works when I compile it alone, but it breaks in my document. I managed to reproduce the problem, it happens when the document is in `twocolumn`. Is it due to the `width=\linewidth`? How can I fix that?

Comment: @Ntakwetet, first you need to edit your question and provide relevant information about your document. Over thumb, try to reduce font size. `\linewidth` works in two column document too, however, in it is diagram narrower (with with of a column). See, if it is acceptable, that image span two columns?

Comment: I just updated it with the MWE with the `twocolumn` class option. Unluckily I don't know what informations are relevant until I don't try a solution: with my original code `twocolumn` wasn't relevant - the chart was broken as well, so I just pruned it =).

I reduced the font size to `\tiny`, but the problem is still there and the labels are barely readable. If nothing else works I'll span the columns, but I would rather prefere not to do so - the result isn't very good-looking (but I can work on that).

Comment: @Ntakwetet, I don't know, what you trying and what is your goal. Apparently you can not put elephant to lady suitcase :-). Possible solution for put image in one column is to rotate node text for 90 degree, however, I would rather span figure over two columns.

Comment: Rotating the text is what I was looking for, in my "real" document it looks better than a spanned figure. Thanks for help!

Comment: @Ntakwetet, see addendum to the my answer.